# Session variable not printing in view in Codeigniter 4

Tags: codeigniter, session-variables, codeigniter-4

in codeigniter 4 I have tried to print the session variable in view using `$session->get('item')`; and `$session->item` as well but unfortunately it does not print. But same variables are printed using `$_SESSION` global variable. can any one guide how to print in view using `$session->get('item')`; or `$session->item`.

The session variables are printing in controller by both methods `$session->get('item')`; and `$session->item`.

Comment: Do you have any sample code that demonstrates what you are trying to do?

Comment: This is how i initiate session as service, $this->session = \Config\Services::session(); then i try to print my session variable by these two method ($session->get('item'); and $session->item) in view but they are not printing. these are two method given by codeigniter session library.

Comment: When you say "print" you are using something like echo $session->get('item'); or <?= $session->get('item');?>

Comment: but now finally i have found solution that is to use default helper function autoloaded by codeigniter. Any session variable can be accessed anywhere like this session('item');

Comment: yes by print i mean these  echo $session->get('item'); or <?= $session->get('item');?>

Answer (score 4):

It's an interesting topic.

Here is some code I used to test this out...

I hijacked the default Home Controller
**app/Controllers/Home.php**

```
protected $session;
public function index()
{
    $this->session = \Config\Services::session();
    $this->session->set('view_data','Hi there I am from the session');

    $page['view_data'] =$this->session->get('view_data'); // Normal way
    $page['session'] =$this->session;                     // Pass in the object

    echo view('test_session_view',$page);

}
```

Then I created a little test file to see what would work...

**app/views/test_session_view.php**

```
<?php
    $local_session = \Config\Services::session(); // Needed for Point 5
?>
<h1>Test_Session_View.php</h1>
<h2>1. Passed in as normal view variable : <?= $view_data; ?></h2>
<h2>2. Passed in as the Session Object : <?= $session->get('view_data'); ?></h2>
<h2>3. The Ole Fashioned SESSION Global way: <?= $_SESSION['view_data']; ?></h2>
<h2>4. The Helper Way: <?= session('view_data'); ?></h2>
<h2>5. The local instance: <?= $local_session->get('view_data'); ?></h2>
```

By default $session (in my case $this->session) is not "global" and so it has to obey the same rules as any other variable passed into a View.

Of course, as you noted, $_SESSION, is directly accessible as it is GLOBAL.

And the session helper (Point 4) gives us even simpler access, as you found.

This led to Point 5 which is what the session helper does. It creates an instance of the session and performs a "get". 
That is in **System\Common.php Line 877**ish **function session(string $val = null)**

So there are a few ways you can access session data in a view.

Comment: is it possible to get session for all the user data for 1 user? I tried  <?= session()->get('username') ?> on my view page, it is working fine but when I tried  <?= session()->get() ?> as per the CI4 documentation, I get an error "ErrorException, Array to string conversion" Is there a way to display all the data? Or do I have to do it 1 line by 1 line in order to display all data?

Comment: Well yes that is absolutely correct. If you try to echo an array - as per the PHP documentation - you will get the error of an array to string conversion, as an array is not a string. You can use use var_dump() or print_r() and friends to display the array in development OR you can use a foreach loop to get at each one individually.

Comment: When I am using header('Location: '.$url); or return redirect()->to($url); so in the new controller i am not getting the session value adding by me before redirecting to new page but system session data is available in new redirected page in codeigniter 4. Please help

Comment: @samiul  I'd suggest you create a new post/question regarding your issue with all the relevant information,